# How to get current system date and time without am/pm Designators using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I set my system region settings to "spanish", So I'm getting the time format like: `20/02/2016 02:39:40 a.m.`  ;I have stored this value in datetime variable and passed to sql database table. I set my *database default language* also to "spanish", at the time of inserting datetime varaible..getting exception

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

due to having "." (preiod) in a.m./p.m. I am getting this exception. I searched a lot on this issue, every where converting the datetime varaible to string format.But I should pass this as a datetime variable only.

So please let me know how to get current system datetime without **am/pm** or without having "." in am/pm

```
 //Here is my code:

    DomainSchema.DOMAINRow drDomain = domain_dataset.DOMAIN.NewDOMAINRow();
    //Assigning the values to the DataRow of the table Domain
       drDomain.CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now;
       drDomain.LAST_UPDT_DATE = DateTime.Now;
       domain_dataset.DOMAIN.AddDOMAINRow(drDomain);
     CultureInfo i;                

  i = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
                if (i.Name == "es-PE")
                {
                   CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
         String s = DateTime.Now.ToString(c); //getting s="20/02/2016 08:07:54"
   DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(s, c, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal); //geting d="20/02/2016 08:07:54 a.m."
}

    //method that uses this dataset

    public override string Create(DataSet ds, string tableName, IDbTransaction transaction, IPrincipal user)
            {
                DataRow dRow = null;
                CommandStatement cmdStatemnt;
                string strResult = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                  dRow = ds.Tables[tableName].Rows[0];
            cmdStatemnt = Execute(dRow, tableName, transaction, true, null, user); 
                   //Here I'm getting exception,conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string,due to having "." in "a.m." 
                }

        }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When passing date/time to databases I always use this

```
Datetime d = DateTime.Today;

String s = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// output   "02/20/2016 12:00:00 AM"

String s = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// output   "02/20/2016 00:00:00"
```

Using capitals HH gives 24-hour format

---

Here you can find a lot more regarding date time formatting

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

---

*Update based on comments*

In the situation described, you should be able to do something like this.

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
String s = DateTime.Now.ToString(c);
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(s, c, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

---

*2nd update based on comments*

2 more ways could be:

- Toggle the culture when running the database transaction

  ```
  // Switch Current Culture
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

  // run database code

  // Switch Back To Origin Current Culture
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
  ```
- Change your dataset object and have the CREATED_DATE typed as string instead of datetime

  After all, when you execute a SQL query, datetime's are treated as string (quoted) in the query, even if the field they are stored in is of datetime type.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am getting the value like:CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now; //Here CREATED_DATE is datetime type in Schema which I can't change, So I can't pass value for this as string type. It throws exception.

Comment: @sam The CREATED_DATE, is that a property in a class you use for the actual database read/write?

Comment: @sam I updated my answer with a suggestion. Also, could you please update your question with the commented code, as comments can be removed and then that info gets lost.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, the outputs that I got at these steps:

Comment: In value "d", I am getting again datetime with a.m.

Comment: I updated my question with your given suggestion, please check once

Comment: @sam With what I know now, I can only see 2 ways; ...1. toggle the [culture at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime) ... 2. change your dataset date's to string (in a sql query, string is the normal way to write date to database)

Comment: Yes..switch the current culture method works for me.. thanks a lot Son

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting that datetime value? Are you doing it like:
    var dt = Datetime.Now;

Comment: CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now; //here CREATED_DATE is datetime type in schema which i can't change, so i don't have option to convert it as  string.

Answer (score 0):

u can using DateTime.Now.ToString("your formate") ,so your time become string type,last, u can insert into database that convert this string to date type with a sql function.