# DataGridView not showing correct cultureinfo

Tags: c#, datagridview, globalization

I have a fairly standard BindingSource / DataGridView combination. The bindingSource has a decimal type property that must be displayed in the DataGridView as a currency. For a test I want to see what it looks like if I use a culture info that uses **€** as currency format instead of **£**

My problem is, that although I programmatically change the CurrentUICulture of the current thread (My application has only one thread), my DataGridView still shows **£**.

The designer created for me the following code snippets:

```
this.columnPriceValue = new Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.columnPriceValue.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
this.columnPriceValue.DataPropertyName = "Value";
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Format = "C4";
...
```

In the constructor of my main form I set the currentUICulture to the Dutch Culture according to a stackoverflow answer [How to change CurrentCulture at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime)

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0013);
```

Because the GBP sign is still shown I checked the currencySymbol just before adding the data to the bindingsource:

```
public void ShowPrices(IEnumerable<Price> prices)
{
    string txt = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
    Debug.WriteLine(txt);   
    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = prices;
    ...
```

The debugger output window shows that **€** is still the Currency Symbol, , yet the DataGridview still shows **£**.

What to do to let it show the euro-sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, not `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

Although the names do seem to imply something different, `CurrentCulture` is actually used to decide what formats to use to display values.

`CurrentUICulture` only has an effect when you use resource dlls and is then only used to decide which resource dll is loaded.

See also [What is the difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties of CultureInfo in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

NineBerry beat me to it as I was editing, but as stated: Just use the following instead:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0013);
```

---

**Previous Answer**:

Try setting the `CultureInfo` for the specific column using the `FormatProvider`:

```
this.columnPriceValue.DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0013);
```

Or if `dataGridViewCellStyle2` is the style for the Price column's cell template:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle2.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(0x0013);
```

---

Or more generically, after setting the `CurrentUICulture`:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle2.FormatProvider = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
```