# how to pass the selected culture into InitializeCulture() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, currentuiculture

I have a login page where the user can select his language through a radio button, after login the user is redirected to Default.aspx where I'm using the below method to set the page culture:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Resources" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<script runat=server>
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["lang"].ToString());
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Session["lang"].ToString());
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
</script>
```

How can I pass the selected language from the login page to this method in Default.aspx page? I tried to pass it through session but I got this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.this[string].get returned null.

Because this method happens in early stages before any control or session is initiated, that's why it returns null. Any idea how can I pass the selected culture to this method?

Comment: Check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I managed to pass the selected culture info using Query String:

in my login page I have those two radio buttons and a button:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="ar-AE" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="en-US" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

in the code behind the button OnClick:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?language=" + RadioButton1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?language=" + RadioButton2.Text);
        }
    }
```

then in Default.aspx page I have this code:

```
<% @Import Namespace="System.Resources" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
<script runat=server>
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Request.QueryString["language"].ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Request.QueryString["language"].ToString());
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
</script>
```

I tried to use Cookie also but it returns null as well like the session, so the query string is the only way that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your code is "lang" loaded into Session?

I believe this is telling you that "lang" doesn't exist in SessionState vs. that SessionState itself is not available.

Comment: in page_load, but the problem is that this method InitializeCulture()
 runs before the page_load, so the session is always empty.

Comment: Try..Catch block doesn't really do anything because it seems like the exception is actually coming from Visual Studio itself.  

Here are the odd behaviors:
- If I just run the code it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting it as a default or allowing the user to choose it?

If the former then just put this in your App.xaml.cs:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
```

Could also do something like this if you worried about thread culture:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name != "en-US")
{
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

Comment: I'm allowing the user to do it, it is easy for me to set it as default in many ways. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

[Change Culture of a webpage as in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" uiculture="auto" %>
> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
> <%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %>
> <script runat="server">
> protected override void InitializeCulture()
> {
>     if (Request.Form["ListBox1"] != null)
>     {
>         String selectedLanguage = Request.Form["ListBox1"];
>         UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
>         Culture = selectedLanguage ;
>
>         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
>             CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
>         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
>             CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
>     }
>     base.InitializeCulture();
> }
> </script>
> ```

Comment: I tried this several times and it never changes the culture to the selected one, it always gives me the OS current culture no matter what. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18753/Developing-an-ASP-NET-page-with-MasterPage-and-Loc