# how to override Windows current culture in order to start an application?

Tags: c#, currentculture, uiculture

I had a .NET  application with resources in French, Deutsche and Spanish. Native resources of the application are in English. My computer's UI culture is set at "en-US" therefore when I run the application, the UI is in English.

I want to execute the application but testing the other languages, without having  to change the language of the OS, neither the code of the application

It is possible?

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime

Comment: @vdefeo No it's not. OP doesn't want to change the code of the application and the thread you linked does exactly that.

Comment: You can force it into your application, check this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ckwb4b(v=vs.100).aspx (as long as you are using resource files)
This can also help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I cannot make changes to the application code