# Set current culture for Blazor component

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app running on .NET Core 3.1 with localization configured as per this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=webassembly). Everything is working great until here, the app is localized and I'm able to switch between languages.

Now, I am trying to render a component with Resource content displayed using a given culture. Here's my attempt using a parent component passing in a given culture name to a child component that should display the localized Resources strings.

```
@using System.Globalization

@foreach(var lang in supportedCultures)
{
    <LocalizedComponent CultureName="@lang" ResourceName="French" />
}

@code {
    private string[] supportedCultures = new[] { "en", "fr", "en-US", "fr-FR", "fr-CA" };
}
```

LocalizedComponent.razor

```
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Threading;

<h3>Content for @GivenCulture.ToString()</h3>
<p>Value from Resource property: @Resource.French</p>
<p>Value from Resource Manager (using GetString method): @Resource.ResourceManager.GetString(ResourceName, GivenCulture)</p>
<p>Value from Localizer: @Localizer[ResourceName]</p>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string CultureName { get; set; }

    private CultureInfo GivenCulture => new CultureInfo(CultureName);

    [Inject]
    private IStringLocalizer<Resource> Localizer { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()  
    {
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = GivenCulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = GivenCulture;

        //same result using:
        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = GivenCulture;

        var temp = Resources.Resource.ResourceManager.GetObject(ResourceName, GivenCulture).ToString();

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}
```

I have the corresponding Resource files created as `Resource.resx` and `Resource.fr.resx`, with a localized string for a Resource "French". The app content is localized just fine when I switch between the languages in the UI, however, the localized component does not display the given culture resources ad-hoc.

Is there a way to force an individual component to display localized content for a given culture in Blazor?

Results:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CurrentCulture at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine thanks, unfortunately, already tried setting the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried setting it in `OnParametersSet` instead of `OnInitializedAsync` ?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Yes, I have as well. Same result.

Comment: Have you find how to fix it?

Comment: @GeorgyTarasov Unfortunately, no. We are working around the issue for now.

Comment: Spent a lot of time figuring this out - debugging [`ResourceManager`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/resources/resourcemanager.cs#L1249) and other classes for a bunch of hours. Something strange is happening in method `GetString(string name, CultureInfo culture)`. I decided to abandon further research. By the way, I found an interesting [article](https://gametorrahod.com/workaround-for-client-side-blazor-localization-with-resx/) about this problem, perhaps it will be useful