# Binary sourced problem to Datagridview with C#

Tags: c#, parameters, datagridview, aes

I have one database and one table. I am trying to pull data from my table in c#. this data is encrypted in aes environment.
For example ihbar_konu table 0x30cb2f045041e388182a4f52193dd44e. I want to print it in c#. but I get an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;



namespace ÇorluİK
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection con;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataReader dr;

        string connectionString = "hidden";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // DataGridView için yeni bir DataTable oluşturun.
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                // Veritabanından verileri almak için SQL sorgusunu hazırlayın.
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT ihbar_konusu FROM corluik";

                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        // Verileri DataTable'a doldurun.
                        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }

            // DataGridView'e DataTable'ı bağlayın.
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        }

    }
}
```

My Error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwPA3.png)

Comment: Do not post images of source code or **errors**, and please ensure the errors are in english. Just set the CurrentCulture/CurrentUICulture for the thread temporarily.

Comment: How to set it up

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000509/how-to-change-currentculture-at-runtime about changing the culture.